# Why do BLDC ESCs have more than 3 mosfets?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

Most of the BLDC ESCs that I've seen use 6 or more mosfets for switching. In my understanding, they should only need 3, one for each lead of the motor. Do they have half-bridges for each lead?

Comment: Yes, they have half-bridges for each lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a half bridge you need two mosfets, a high side switch and a low side switch to reverse the current. The reason for a full bridge is so you can reverse the current (and voltage polarity) on a load.

The diagram below shows a whole bridge (two half bridges) and why you need two switches.

This can be extended to three half bridges in a bldc motor since one half bridge is on, one half bridge on but on the low side (is sinking current) and the third bridge is off. These are constantly switching but this gives you the general idea.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDMnJr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is the ability to switch polarity used to brake the motor or make it spin in the opposite direction? What if the motor only needs to spin in one direction?

Comment: A BLDC motor works by creating a rotating magnetic field positioned in the right place with respect to the (typically) permanent magnets on the rotor.  In order to create this field, each winding needs to have an AC current with the correct sign and phase, and the sign can be positive or negative.  Therefore for motion in one direction you still need bidirectional currents in each of the phases.  It's possible with other motor types like switched-reluctance to operate with unipolar currents, but that's a whole different story.

Comment: @JohnD Oh okay, I got it. Thanks. So, one of the leads acts at ground?

Comment: At any given time any of the leads can be switched to ground via the half-bridge, but there's no one lead that's sitting at ground potential permanently.

Comment: Yeah, a mosfet is a 'switch' when on it is low resistance\impedance and allows current to flow so its is not quite ground (if you measure the voltage across it it will be mV or less normally) but close.

Comment: @JohnD So, at any given time, there is one lead acting as source for the motors, one acting as ground, and one floating?

Comment: Possibly.  There are different schemes for driving BLDC motors.  Six-step commutation operates as you describe but sinusoidal PWM or space-vector modulation are used as well and your description would not necessarily hold in those cases.  And I would say "not driven" rather than floating.

Comment: @JohnD Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer is fine enough, I will give my +1 when the schematic of a typical (star or delta) BLDC winding with three half bridges is added.

Comment: Nah, its too messy with three